# java.lang.NullPointerException - Java server and C client

Tags: java, c, network-programming

I'm trying to implement Java server and C client. I get java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to send string multiple times.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EchoServer
{        
    ServerSocket m_ServerSocket;


    public EchoServer() 
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the server socket.
            m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(12111);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not create server socket at 12111. Quitting.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Listening for clients on 12111...");

        // Successfully created Server Socket. Now wait for connections.
        int id = 0;
        while(true)
        {                        
            try
            {
                // Accept incoming connections.
                Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();

                // accept() will block until a client connects to the server.
                // If execution reaches this point, then it means that a client
                // socket has been accepted.

                // For each client, we will start a service thread to
                // service the client requests. This is to demonstrate a
                // multithreaded server, although not required for such a
                // trivial application. Starting a thread also lets our
                // EchoServer accept multiple connections simultaneously.

                // Start a service thread

                ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
                cliThread.start();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception encountered on accept. Ignoring. Stack Trace :");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new EchoServer();    
    }


    class ClientServiceThread extends Thread
    {
        Socket m_clientSocket;        
        int m_clientID = -1;
        boolean m_bRunThread = true;

        ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int clientID)
        {
            m_clientSocket = s;
            m_clientID = clientID;
        }

        public void run()
        {            
            // Obtain the input stream and the output stream for the socket
            // A good practice is to encapsulate them with a BufferedReader
            // and a PrintWriter as shown below.
            BufferedReader in = null; 
            PrintWriter out = null;

            // Print out details of this connection
            System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + m_clientID + " : Address - " + 
                             m_clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            try
            {                                
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(m_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

                // At this point, we can read for input and reply with appropriate output.

                // Run in a loop until m_bRunThread is set to false
                while(m_bRunThread)
                {                    
                    // read incoming stream
                    String clientCommand = in.readLine();

                    System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);


                    if(clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                    {
                        // Special command. Quit this thread
                        m_bRunThread = false;   
                        System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + m_clientID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Echo it back to the client.
                        out.println(clientCommand);
                        out.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up
                try
                {                    
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    m_clientSocket.close();
                    System.out.println("...Stopped");
                }
                catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 


#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    char buffer[256] = "some string\n";
    char buff[256] = "quit\n";
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;

    if (3 != argc) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <server> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    /* create a streaming socket      */
    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for connecting */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[2]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use the IP address sent as an argument for the server address  */
    bzero(&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_addr(argv[2], &simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  connect to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = connect(simpleSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer, sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect successful!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }

    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    send(simpleSocket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
//    read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    /* get the message from the server   */
//    returnStatus = read(simpleSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        fprintf(stderr, "Return Status = %d \n", returnStatus);

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

I get this error message into the Java server.

```
Accepted Client : ID - 2 : Address - localhost
Client Says :some string
Client Says :some string
Client Says :some string
Client Says :some string
Client Says :quit
Client Says :
Client Says :null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EchoServer$ClientServiceThread.run(EchoServer.java:102)
...Stopped
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: "if(clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `clientCommand` is `null` and as a result you get the `NullPointerException`.

From your log output I see that you print `quit` and so you should have gone to the branch were you do `m_bRunThread = false;` and stop reading.

But instead you continue printing/reading after that as show the logs.

I suggest 2 things to try:
Declare the boolean as `volatile`

```
volatile boolean m_bRunThread = true;
```

and take into account empty space: `clientCommand.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")`

Actually do it defencively as follows:

```
 while(m_bRunThread) {                    
       // read incoming stream
       String clientCommand = in.readLine();    
       if(clientCommand == null || "".equals(clientCommand.trim()){  
         bRunThread = false;//here you could also do break and just use a while(true)  
       }  
       //go on with the code
```